# Port redirection for domain

Tags: nginx, dns, glassfish, debian, port

I have NGINX on my VPS working on port 80 (few domains on it), and I want add GlassFish on port 8080.

Next I want add domain for GlassFish, but on domain it should work on port 80.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Him add server rule, for example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name demo.glass.fish;

    location /  {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add this to NGINX config? @siavolt